# Access - Open a new record and populate a textbox using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to populate a textbox on a form using VBA. I want it to first open the form, then go to a New record and then populate a textbox on that New record.

```
Private Sub btn_AddAccount()
DoCmd.OpenForm "tbl_MonitorAccounts", , , , acFormAdd, acDialog, NewData
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me.MonitorAccount = "FUNC00265"
End Sub
```

Please help me because the code above does not work unfortunately.

Edit: I think it has to do something with that the field is bound. Is it possible to populate bound records using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Changing acFormAdd to acFormEdit was the easy solution.

```
Private Sub btn_AddAccount()
DoCmd.OpenForm "tbl_MonitorAccounts", , , , acFormEdit, acDialog, NewData
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me.MonitorAccount = "FUNC00265"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, can populate bound control. I expect it doesn't work because the form opens in Dialog mode and this suspends code execution in the calling procedure which resumes when the Dialog form closes.

Have code behind Dialog form populate textbox if condition is met. The code opens form in Add mode so should not need more code to move to new record, should already be on new record row. Example:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord Then
    Me.MonitorAccount = "FUNC00265"
End If
End Sub
```

Or can pass value to the Dialog form with OpenArgs and do something depending on what is in OpenArgs. Ex: `If Me.OpenArgs Like "Edit*" Then`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code works. I want to populate this field with a buttonclick from another form. However, now each time when it generates a new record it populates a field with "FUNC00265". But I have five other accounts FUNC00266, FUNC00267 etc. Can I still use this method?

Comment: Yes. You will have to dynamically set the Global variable or OpenArgs. Where will that value come from? Will user select it from a combobox? If so, reference the combobox: `DoCmd.OpenForm "tbl_MonitorAccounts", , , , acFormAdd, acDialog, Me.comboboxName`. What is NewData for?